Ruby REPL's errors and REPL freezing
I'm new to Ruby and am currently working on a scraper on vsc (Windows OS). I downloaded the nokogiri, watir, and pry gems, and I've been opening a pry REPL to run a few basic commands that test my scraper. These are pretty fundamental commands:
require "nokogiri"
require "watir"
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)

^After this command, an empty browser does open, but after that my REPL immediately freezes and stops this was a couple days ago. I tried coming back to it again today, and alongside freezing, I also got the following error:
ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(878)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100

I attached screenshots below as well, and even tried taking a step down to try this on the irb REPL (no luck). Absolutely clueless on this and would love to put this behind me to continue creating. Would be incredibly grateful for any help I can get.

Thank you!

That's strange, I assumed all the images I had posted were of my terminal. Must've gotten mixed up when uploading. Thank you!

Why are you saying new Watir::Browser.new(:chrome) in your screen shot? Don't you want just Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)?

I realized that a bit after posting this! Unfortunately, removing that error didn't fix the glitch either

Please don't just post photos, especially of code or errors. Whatever DevTools is, you have something trying to open a WebSocket and failing an SSL handshake. You might be missing an SSL library, a certificate, or have some other problem, but the underlying issue is still an SSL handshake failure of some kind.
